# Recursive function finding max value

Tags: java, recursion

I feel like I am pretty close, but my return value keeps printing out the first value in the array..

```
public static double mx(int[] nums, int track)  
maxNow = nums[0];
if (count < [lengthofarray] - 1 && nums[track] != 0) 
{
    if (numbers[track] > maxval)
    maxval = numbers[track];
    System.out.println(maxval);
    return maxval = mx(nums, track+1);          
}
else
return maxval;
}
```

Comment: Never omit braces in a multiline IF block.

Comment: `currentMax` always equals the first value in the array.  So you eventually just return that value either because it's bigger than some other value or because you reach the end of the array.

Comment: Also, separate the `return currentMax...` into two lines: `currentMax = ...; return currentMax;`. It's not technically required, but good convention to follow.

Comment: Either `currentMax` should be a private static field or, better yet, it should be part of the argument list to the method.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to fix that, I have been staring at it for a while..

Comment: Why are you using recursion where a simple `for` loop would suffice?

Comment: what is `int count` ?

Comment: @dcharms I'm guess it's an exercise in recursive functions.

Comment: @dcharms Teachers love to assign inappropriate uses of recursion in order to teach recursion.  I think I've seen dozens of them here on SO, including some cases where a recursive approach would be extremely convoluted compared to a double loop or something.  It's a disease, and I wish I knew how to eradicate it.

Comment: Yes, my prof is teaching us recursion atm. int count is the current position of the element in the array

Comment: Please dont' deface your question.

Comment: @ajb Well, it's good practice for people to write things like Fibonacci recursively, so that they can learn to _think_ appropriately about problems. That being said, I think SO will see questions like this until doomsday.

Comment: @Azar Fibonacci is one of the _worst_ uses of recursion, because it results in lower `F(n)` values being computed multiple times.  If anything, maybe people should write things like Fibonacci recursively so that they can see how inappropriate it can be.

Comment: @ajb I'm aware of that. My point is that it can be helpful to learn recursion through methods like Fibonacci, which naturally lend themselves to a recursive solution. Yes, perhaps one should include a disclaimer about its inefficiency, but it's the concept that is being taught, not dynamic programming or the most efficient way to calculate the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: I remember my freshman year of college when we learned recursion.  The very first thing we did was the Fibonacci sequence and one of the first things we learned was how easy it was to create a stack-overflow with that recursive method.  Recursion is very powerful and often times the recursive solution is much easier to code and much more elegant (of course, it's almost never the most efficient way).  There's nothing wrong with this assignment.  The assignment wasn't to write the best possible findMax function--it was to learn about recursion.

Answer (score 2):

`currentMax` is a local variable declared inside `findMax`.  This means that if `findMax` calls itself, which calls itself again, which calls itself again, so that it's now on the stack four times, there will be four different `currentMax` variables; each `findMax` has its own.  Thus, if one of those `findMax` invocations modifies `currentMax`, it only modifies its own; the modification has no effect on the local `currentMax` variables belonging to the other invocations of `findMax`.

There are ways to get the method invocations to share the same `currentMax` (passing it as a parameter, as suggested in another answer, is a possibility), but you don't need them here.  Instead, look at the problem a little differently: If you want to find the maximum of `numbers[3]` through `numbers[10]`, you can call your function recursively to find the maximum of `numbers[4]` through `numbers[10]`, **then** look at `numbers[3]` and compare it against the maximum you found recursively.

P.S. I do not recommend making `currentMax` a static field in order to get it to be shared; using a global field to hold results of recursion is usually poor programming practice, in my view.  (It introduces thread-unsafety, for one thing.)  There are ways to do this if done carefully, but in general I believe it should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

try to simplify the code:

```
public static int findMax(int[] numbers, int count){
    if (count > 0) {
        return Math.max(numbers[count], findMax(numbers, count-1))
    } 

   else {
        return numbers[0];
   }
}
```

Comment: `numbers[count]` is out of range.

Comment: call this with `findMax(numbers, numbers.length-1)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can visualize this problem:

Your data can look like

```
{a, b, c, d, e}
```

you need to find max using

```
max(a, max(restOfElements))
```

which means you need to again use

```
max(a, max(b, max(restOfElements)))
.
.
.
max(a, max(b, max(c, max (d, max(e, nothing)))))
```

and last case can be visualized even better as

```
max(a,  .      .      .       .                )
       max(b,  .      .       .               )
              max(c,  .       .              )
                     max (d,  .             )
                             max(e, nothing)
```

So in the end you have two cases

1. when you are handling `e`, where you can't compare it with anything
2. when you are comparing current value with max of values after it

- To handle first case you just need to return `e` because there is nothing else to compare it with.
- To handle second case just get max value from rest of elements, compare it with your current value and return greater one.

Here is how your code can look like (hover over box to see code, but before you do it, try to implement it yourself again)

> `public static double findMax(double[] numbers, int count) {
>     if (count == numbers.length - 1)//we are handling last element
>         return numbers[count];
>
>     //else, we are returning greater number between current element, 
>     //and max from rest of elements
>     return Math.max(numbers[count], findMax(numbers, count + 1));
> }`

Usage example:

```
double[] arr = { 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3 };
System.out.println(findMax(arr, 0));
```

Output: `4.0`

---

As an exercise instead of dividing your problem in`max(a, max(b, max(c, max(d, max(e))))` try to create method which will do it like `max(max(max(max(max(a), b), c), d), e)`

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the purpose of `&& numbers[count] != 0`? What if all your numbers are negative?

Second, try passing the currentmax as an argument, instead of initializing it inside the method. You want to keep track of your currentMax. Initializing it as a local variable would not do that, but would reset it to the first element at each call.

```
public static double findMax(double[] numbers, int count, double currentMax)  
{
if (count < numbers.length)// && numbers[count] != 0) //While the value of count remains lower than the size of the array and the current element of the arraylist doesn't = 0, the execute the code..
{
    if (numbers[count] > currentMax)
        currentMax = numbers[count];
    return currentMax = findMax(numbers, count+1, currentMax);          
}
else return currentMax;
}
```

Comment: Use of the `currentMax` argument leads to tail recursion, which is a good thing.

Comment: What is exactly is the point of checking for it? If your array contains {-1,-2,0}, once it gets to 0, it will skip it and return the currentMax (which would be -1). So it would be incorrect if you left that condition in there. Also, get rid of the "-1" in the first condition.

Answer (score 0):

Well since we're giving out answers, here's how I would do it:

max(arr[1-n]) = max(arr[1], max(arr[2-n]);

```
public static double findMax(final double ...arr){
    return findMax(arr, 0);
}

private static double findMax(final double[] arr, final int start){
    // base case, if this is the end of the array, the max of the "rest" 
    //  is just this element
    if(start == arr.length - 1)
        return arr[start];
    // else continue

    // find the max of the rest of the array
    final double nextMax = findMax(arr, start + 1);
    // return this index if it's greater than the next max, 
    //  else return the next max
    return arr[start] > nextMax ? arr[start] : nextMax;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my try at it:

```
 public static double findMax(double[] numbers, int count, double currentMax){

        if( count < numbers.length ){
            if( numbers[count] > currentMax ){
                currentMax = numbers[count];                    
            }

            currentMax = findMax( numbers, count+1, currentMax );
        }
        return currentMax;
    }
```